# Put pipe value into variable

Tags: bash, shell

I'm new in bash scripting world...

I'm trying to get value from pipe action to a var.

Something like:

result = $(ls /usr/bin | dmenu)

the idea is put files list into a standar menu (dmenu) so, when user select 
a choice, i want to know wich one is selected and work with this option
to for example, execute  a file.

the $result is not getting any value.

Thanks for your help

Comment: The other question doesn't make the exact same mistake, but the answer given (showing correct usage without excess whitespace) is on-point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove whitespaces before and after `=`:

```
result=$(ls /usr/bin | dmenu)
```